# Is There a Way To Cache And Distribute Visual Studio Updates Over a LAN?

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio

Every new update of visual studio is the same thing at my job. Eventually, one developer gets stuck with the updating process waiting for the huge download and copy of files to finish (it gets worse when more developers are also updating due to the effects on bandwidth).

Is there a way to cache and distribute these updates over a local network so its impact on bandwidth, productivity etc could be reduced, something like WSUS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the instructions on the MSDN for "[Installing Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/e2h7fzkw.aspx)"

> **Downloading Visual Studio for an offline installation**
>
> ---
>
> In most cases, you can install Visual Studio from the download site
>   with no problems. However, in some cases, you may want to download all
>   the update packages before you install them (for example, to install
>   on multiple machines or on an offline machine). The following steps
>   explain how to download all the update packages that you need for an
>   offline installation.
>
> 1. After you download the update executable from the MSDN website to a location on your file system, run the following command at a command
>      prompt: `<executable name> /layout`.
>
>    This command downloads all the packages for the installation.
>
>    By using the `/layout` switch, you can download almost all the core
>      installation packages, not just the ones that apply to the download
>      machine. This approach gives you all the files that you need to run
>      this update anywhere and may be useful if you want to install
>      components that weren't installed originally.
> 2. After you run the command, you should be prompted for the download location. Enter the location, and then choose **Download**.
> 3. When the package download is successful, you should see a Visual Studio screen that says **Setup Successful! All specified components
>      have been acquired successfully**.
> 4. In the file location that you specified, find the executable file and the package folder. This is everything you need to copy to a
>      shared location or install media.
>
>    **Caution:** Currently, the Android SDK does not support an offline installation
>      experience. If you install Android SDK Setup items on a computer that
>      is not connected to the internet, the installation might fail.
> 5. You can now run the installation from the file location or the install media.

This process can be done with the update exe

```
VS2015.1.exe /layout C:\VSUpdate\2015.1
```

this would download and copy the update files to `C:\VSUpdate\2015.1` which then could be put on a network share for the other developers to use.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are searching for [portable update](http://www.portableupdate.com/). 
its cache can reside on any usb external drive or, via private lan network, on a shared path. Once an update is copied to the cache (the only time that an internet connection is required), the same update will be used for all computer that need that particular update.
read this [article](https://www.maketecheasier.com/download-windows-updates-and-install-on-multiple-pcs/) too.

Comment: I see it works fine for system updates, but am not sure it works the same for updates of independent applications (as is the case of visual studio). I will give it a test and tell you whether it worked or not.

Comment: I'm not sure but you can give it a try

Comment: It didn't. But thanks! This tool helped me solve a different problem I had with Windows Updates. :-)

Comment: yea it is handy for lowering network traffic caused by windows update

Comment: As well as to bypass stupid restrictions imposed by some corporate security solutions which block Windows Update.